# My application crashes when moving from one view(Java Class) to another

Tags: java, android

So I've been working on a music player in android studio and I've created two java classes. One for Main Start Screen(StartScreen.Java) and one for the main player (player.Java).
I have an onClicl event associated with a button as shown below.

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, main_player.class);
    startActivity(detailIntent);
}
```

The code for the second Java Class is as below. There is nothing in the java class as for now.

```
package com.example.musicplayer.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class main_player extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.player);

}
}
```

The code in the manifest is as below.

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".StartScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".main_player"
        android:label="@string/main_player"
        android:parentActivityName=".StartScreen">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".StartScreen"/>
    </activity>
```

Can you please tell me where is the actual mistake because the app works fine until i click the button that is suppose to take me to the main player screen?

Thank You

Comment: can you post the LogCat of the crash?

Comment: Thank you JRowan. As soon as i uploaded this post i realized that i had missed this line 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put "super"?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.player);

}
```

Comment: I didnt at first. This was the main reason for the crash :p